# xml android Guideline constraint layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, textview, android-constraintlayout

I need your help :)

My question is regarding the use of `Constraint Guideline` to separate my screen.

I do not know if it is the best way of doing things for separating the document, but I wanna try this one.

My question is the following :

I want to separate my screen in two horizontal part. The second part will include 3 or 4 guidelines.

I can find how to do that. If you also can help me on this part (this is message is for the second `TextView` on my `xml` code : "this view is not constrained horizontally. At run time it will jump to the left unless you had a horizontal constrained."

I would like something like that :

[image]

Here is the code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/test"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="blablabla"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="buenos dias"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/test" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="buenos dias"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/test" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="buenos dias"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guidelineTwo"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/test" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="buenos dias"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guidelineThree"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/test" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.25" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guidelineTwo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guidelineThree"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.75" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guidelineFour"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="1" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a horizontal guideline with `app:layout_constraintGuide_percent` of `0.5` to be exactly in the half of the screen/ConstraintLayout height.

Then add top constraints of the `test` TextView to this horizontal guide line instead of the parent.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/test"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="blablabla"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/guideline_horizontal" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="buenos dias"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/test" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="buenos dias"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/test" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="buenos dias"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guidelineTwo"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/test" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="buenos dias"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guidelineThree"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/test" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.25" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guidelineTwo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guidelineThree"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.75" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guidelineFour"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="1" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```